# How do I read the SMPL chunk of a WAV file with C#?

Tags: c#, naudio

I need to read the `dwStart` and `dwEnd` properties within the SMPL chunk because those points should specify the startpoint and endpoint of the loop in sample. 
I'm converting my Directwave libraries to Bitwig’s .multisample format so my app doesn't need to play the WAV file. It just needs to read the loop points so it can be added to an XML that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<multisample name="Test Bell">
    <generator>Bitwig Studio</generator>
    <category>Bell</category>
    <creator>John</creator>
    <description>Misc</description>
    <layer name="Default">
        <sample file="Bell_004 - C3.wav" gain="0.00" sample-start="0.000" sample-stop="88048.000">
            <key track="true" tune="0.00">
                <velocity />
                <loop mode="sustain" start="58709.000" stop="88048.000" />
            </key>
        </sample>
    </layer>
</multisample>
```

**UPDATE:**
Mark Heath's code works to find the *smpl* chunk and loop points in Kontakt WAVs but it doesn't find the an *smpl* chunk in the WAV files created by DirectWave For example this file: 
http://stash.reaper.fm/28963/Flute_006_C3.wav

I used the code below and it only found an ***inst*** chunk. How can I find the start and end loop points if there is no ***smpl*** chunk?

```
    var smp = reader.ExtraChunks.Where(ec => ec.IdentifierAsString != null); 
            foreach (var x in smp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.IdentifierAsString.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NAudio `WaveFileReader` to explore extra chunks. Here's some code for the "smpl" chunk:

```
var wavFilePath = @"E:\Recording\sfz\Equinox Steinway D\SteinwayDmA#0.wav";
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(wavFilePath))
{
    var smp = reader.ExtraChunks.FirstOrDefault(ec => ec.IdentifierAsString == "smpl");
    if (smp != null)
    {
        var chunkData = reader.GetChunkData(smp);
        // https://sites.google.com/site/musicgapi/technical-documents/wav-file-format#smpl
        var midiNote = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData,12);
        var numberOfSamples = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData,28);
        Console.WriteLine($"MIDI {midiNote}, {numberOfSamples} samples");
        int offset = 36;
        for (int n = 0; n < numberOfSamples; n++)
        {
            var cuePointId = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData,offset);
            var type = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData, offset + 4); // 0 = loop forward, 1 = alternating loop, 2 = reverse

            var start = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData, offset + 8);
            var end = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData, offset + 12);
            var fraction = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData, offset + 16);
            var playCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(chunkData, offset + 20);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sample {cuePointId} Start {start} End {end}");
            offset+= 24;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Mark. While testing your code on several Wav files, I realized that some of my Wav files don't have an SMPL chunk even though they have loop points when loaded into a sampler (Bitwig/FL Studio). I used a _for loop_ and **IdentifierAsString** to iterate through the collection of chunks and only found **"inst"**? Is it possible to put the loop points in another chunk?

Comment: sure, there are lots of ways loop points might be stored in a chunk. For example ACID loops have their own chunk format. You'd need to do some research / reverse-engineering to find out what's inside an inst chunk